# read json from local file returned html?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios

I'm not sure what's wrong when my data.json return strange text when I call it.

```
axios.get('./data.json').then(resp => {
      console.log(resp)
      console.log(resp.data)
    })
```

Tried JSON.parse(resp) it doesn't seem to work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/306ynznkk5

Comment: What strange text?

Comment: That `codesandbox.io` just doesn't seem to work. When you enter the JSON url, it responds with the default HTML. File a bug with them.

Comment: The sandbox within CodeSandbox seems to be flawed, your code is correct. Try opening your website in a local test server. Run 'npm install -g http-server' then run 'http-server -o' in a terminal inside your website root folder and you'll see that your site runs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need axios to get data from json file. axios is a library to make XHR request to server. of course "./data.json" is not a url. Then output from your function is text not found.

```
import React from 'react';
...
import data from './data.json';
```

and try to `console.log(data);`

Comment: This doesn't answer why his code doesn't work when it should.